# What's Telegram chat memory space limit?

Tags: api, cloud, storage, telegram

The Telegram has a cloud storage for users self-chat. Limit for uploading files - 1.5GB, yeah, I know about it. But I didn't find something about space limit for a chat. Is it unlimited? I mean, if yes, I can create Telegram-bot for cloud storage? Just, I have more than 20TB files and can I use Telegram for my site files storage and don't be afraid for safety/keeping?

Comment: It's not preferable to use telegram as a server for static files.
you can use something like now.sh or netlify.com there are many platforms that offer services for free you can check them out too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Telegram didn't limit your total storage in each chat.
2. You can use bots to upload and download files, but it has [size limit](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#handling-media).

Comment: No, there is way to uplod files up to 1.5GB via script. So if there are no limit for chat it is great!

Answer (score 0):

[There are no storage limits](https://github.com/tallero/pgpgram).

In general it is not adviced to store backups unencrypted on cloud, so check the above link.